# Can Karabiner perform complex mapping to make British key layout function more like the US layout?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, software-recommendation, internationalization

My MacBook Pro has a British/European keyboard and would like to do the following remaps so my keyboard behaves more like a US keyboard.

Specifically, the more complicated items I need to change are:

1. § (section) map to nothing (or to some modifier+key combo but I never use this key so it doesn't matter)
2. Tilde_Grave_Accent map to § (section)
3. left shift map to Tilde_Grave_Accent (constantly hitting tilde when I want to use shift)

I don't know if this tool is up to the job so I'm looking for a way to make precise changes to the British layout instead of wholly adopting a different layout in software. Which tools are fit for this purpose?

Comment: Is this the result you want?  tilde on top left corner, bottom left corner (key to left of z) switched from a character to an additional shift key?.  First of these is really simple with Ukelele, I already have custom layout that does it.  But getting an extra shift key requires something else.

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I want. Due to the small size of the left shift key, I find I often press the tilde key by mistake, so I want to move the tilde to the section key because I'll never use that.

Comment: Ok, so I've managed to do the 3 key re-maps exactly the way I wanted with Karabiner using only simple modifications. I found out through other posts that in Karabiner, "non_us_backslash" refers to the § section key.  
  
My re-maps were:  
1. **backslash** to **Return**. 
2. **non_us_backslash** (section key) to **grave_accent_and_tilde**. 
3. **grave_accent_and_tilde** to **left_shift**. 
  
I did add one complex modification to access backslash by using the right command key. That one is available here: [https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/]